# Shell append order (>>)

Tags: shell, unix

```
exec 1>>${LOG}
```

I'm running some Shell scripts to check DB parameters. Its the same scripts that runes at 3 diferent times and generates a big log with each run output.

The problem is the order I need the big output to be in order as I run it. (First run = top of the file, 3rd run = bottom) And I'm getting this order 3rd - 1rst - 2nd o_o

Any advice?

Comment: The output will be in the order of execution. If you're getting a different order then it's possible that the output from one of the commands is going through stderr. try redirecting `2>>${LOG}` in the exec as well

Comment: If you run the script on three different places on unknown times (or maybe interleaving), this bash script alone can not possible know how to order that. The simplest thing would be to output each run into a temporary logfile and concatenate them together after they are all finished

Comment: @dirkk may I suggest you post this as an answer? I think this is a better solution to the _actual_ problem than whatever hack we come up with for the question as it was asked.

Comment: @CompuChip I obeyed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was suggested to post my comment as an answer I will obey... However, it is actually not much at all. You could execute your shell scripts and output to some tmp files, e.g. running separately

```
exec 1 >> ${LOG}.tmp1 
exec 1 >> ${LOG}.tmp2
exec 1 >> ${LOG}.tmp3
```

and them concatenate them

```
cat ${LOG}.tmp1 ${LOG}.tmp2 ${LOG}.tmp3 >> ${LOG}
```

You might want to delete the temp files after that

```
rm ${LOG}.tmp*
```

Comment: you can use cat ${LOG}.tmp* >> ${LOG} to get rid of the separate ones.

Comment: @pkawar Does that guarantee that they are `cat`ed in the right order?